# How to get relative path to a file in cache

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to get the relative path to a file inside a app/cache dir.

I've tried via custom config file using:

```
parameters:    
output_dat_path : %kernel.root_dir%/cache/%kernel.environment%/myfile.dat
```

Also I tried:

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel'); 
$path = $kernel->getRootDir() . '/cache/' . $kernel->getEnvironment() . 'myfile.dat';
```

Both ways generate absolute paths, that both work fine using them inside a controller or service, but, I need a relative path to generate a link for the user.

I'm thinking to move the file to the web directory in my service and use asset in the template to generate the link, but the file is private for every user and I don't want to expose it.

Any thought?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I solved this as follows:

1. User, once authenticated, generates his file. If the file doesn't exists, is generated. If it exists, the controller checks the user rights, time, etc. and returns the file.
2. If the system has to be generated, the file is created in a private folder and an encrypted name is generated. The encrypted name is generated using base_64 and some changes after that.
3. The system shows to the user a link. That link is something like /get/privatefile/eDfa...23Hn
4. When the user clicks on it, the controller checks the user, time from creation, etc.
5. If all is fine the controller returns the file.

I made this because the file must be created once, and be available for a short period of time and after must be deleted. If an user pass the link to other person, the checksum of the encrypted name fails and the file cannot be accessed.

I am sure that this is not the best solution but it works right know.

Comment: Yet, you can use `"%kernel.cache_dir%"`. What do you mean by "Relative"? Relative to what? Please, provide an example of a relative path you expect.

Comment: I mean, a path like '../dir/file.dat'

Comment: You want a cache file to be accessible from the web? It doesn't sound like a good idea to expose the `app` folder to the web. Moreover, the cache folder will be deleted as soon as you run the `cache:clear` command. Are you sure this is the behaviour you *need*?

Comment: I need that an user, for a short period of time, would be able to download a file generated. That file contains private information. I think I have a possible solution, generate a url that calls a controller action and that controller get the file and send it using a response object.